# How to delay a method's repeated execution?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to constantly add "zombie" entity to my game after a delay, and then shortening the delay as time goes on.

In my `PlayState` class I've got the code to spawn the entities in a position when my `update();` method is run (which houses `getInput();` and such. Not shown for clarity.)

```
public void update(long elapsed) {
    this.entities.add(new Zombie(-535));
}
```

How would i make a delay that shortens? I'm guessing I would make the delay and then use a multiplier which i have getting smaller every 10 seconds or so, but how would I do this?

Comment: Well, you could ask yourself what is the "time" that goes on. Is it the number of waves that already flowed? Maybe you could use a counter then? Otherwise, you could use a Timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I don't know much about the finer workings of your class, but this might give you a general idea of what I mean:

```
int counter = 50;
for(int i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(i == counter)
    {
        counter = counter / 2;
        this.entities.add(new Zombie(-535));
    }
}
```

Suppose `i` is the the total run-time of the game, and `counter` represents a percent of the game when you want to add a zombie.

If you want to add a zombie after 50% of the run-time (here, 100 seconds), then as the time reduces, you check if the time has come to add a zombie (Here, 50 seconds).

What I've done here is reduce the delay to half, and continue checking if the time has come to add a zombie.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could call sleep on your thread of execution:

```
int sleepInMs = 5000
Thread.sleep(sleepInMs);
sleepInMs+=1000; //Then of course handle the case when sleepInMs == 0
```

Really need more information about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple delay, use "delay ms;"
Edit ms for the number of milliseconds you want. 1000 milliseconds is one second